# Javascript code snippet explanation

Tags: javascript

I have seen this trick question online without any answer or description. Not sure what's going on here:

```
function identity() {
    var name = 'Jack';
    alert(name);
    return
    name
};
var who = identity();
alert(who)
```

This snipped outputs, jack & then undefined, why?

Comment: What's your expectation of what should happen, and why?

Comment: I think it should output jack each time because the function is getting called twice.

Comment: It's bad practice to not use semi-colons, add those in and remove the whitespace between return/name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`identity` is a function. `who` then declares a new instance of that, which we can tell from the func that it will create a local variable `name` and assign `jack` to it, then alert.

The function then looks like it `return` nothing (although `name` is on the next line, so I'd imagine you want to return that, change to `return name;`).

Answer (score 7):

Change this

```
return
name
```

to this:

```
return name;
```

The return statement is one of the few places where javascript does not like whitespace. EDIT. What's happening in the original is the browser inserts a semicolon after the return statement, like this

```
return;
name // this gets ignored
```

So the return value is undefined.TehShrike links to a very good document explaining the exact rules ECMAAScript environments must follow when ignoring whitespace/line breaks and when semicolons must be inserted.

The ECMAScript standard says this (among other things)

> Certain ECMAScript statements (empty statement, variable statement,
>   expression statement, do-while statement, continue statement, break
>   statement, return statement, and throw statement) must be terminated
>   with semicolons. Such semicolons may always appear explicitly in the
>   source text. For convenience, however, such semicolons may be omitted
>   from the source text in certain situations. These situations are
>   described by saying that semicolons are automatically inserted into
>   the source code token stream in those situations.

Comment: Specifically, Javascript's [automatic semicolon insertion](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) adds a semicolon to the end of the `return` line.

Comment: You might also want to answer the actual question (why it returns `undefined`).

Comment: This is a lot of upvotes for an answer talking past the question.

Comment: That's why we are encouraged to improve our answers. :)